# Drop table in access using oledb in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I am trying to delete the whole table created in access through coding in c#.

I am currently using the following coding:

```
      string dstr = "DROP TABLE [" + in_table + "] ";
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(dstr, con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting a syntax error in the above command. I try without square brackets also, but the error remains the same.

I know there must be some silly mistake in the above command, but if anyone can put the correct command, I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `in_table` has some valid table name. Put a break point and watch. Also you may put semicolon (;) at the end of the statement (not compulsory though).